# The hybrid-analysis API does not return URL findings

Tags: python, python-3.x

API for hybrid-analysis is not working.When I enter the API key and execute the code below, it only outputs:

> {'message': 'Requested URI - Not Found'}.

```
import requests

api_key = 'MY_KEY'

# 検証するURL
url_to_scan = 'https://www.google.com/'

# URLスキャンのリクエスト
response = requests.post(
    'https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/api/v2/urls/analyze', 
    headers={'api-key': api_key},
    data={'url': url_to_scan}
)

# スキャン結果を取得
scan_result = response.json()

# 分析結果の表示
print(scan_result)
```

I tried various other URLs, but they did not return any results at all. Am I using it incorrectly?
Please help.

Comment: I do not see anything called `urls/analyze` in the public docs? https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/docs/api/v2